# VS2022 won't save my GitHub personal access token for their nuget registry

Tags: visual-studio, github-package-registry

I get prompted every time I open a project to enter my password (personal access token). I can see it's stored in Windows credential manager but nothing seems to persist it.

Not sure if this is Windows, VS2022, or GitHub but any advice would be appreciated.